# How do I sort an array of different times?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, algorithm, sorting

So I have an array of various timeslots, but I want to sort out the times from the earliest ones to the latest ones, however, I also want to delete any elements within the array that has the time value of 12:00am.

```
Appointment(0) = #10:45:00 AM#
Appointment(1) = #12:00:00 AM# 'My actual has up 80 elements of different timeslots but I'm using 3 elements as an example
Appointment(2) = #12:00:00 AM#
```

Is there anyone who can help me with this problem?

Comment: Is this for homework? (i.e. do you have to use an array, or are other data structures okay?)

Comment: It's a programming assignment for my college, and yes I've structured the main algorithms in my code based on the arrays so I can't use any other data structure

Comment: Are you allowed to use a built-in sort?

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure how to go about it with that method

Answer (score 0):

Using a string array is not a good idea if that's what you used just use a list of **DateTime** and the **Sort** method.

```
Dim list As List(of DateTime) = new List(of DateTime)
For Each val As String In Appointment
    list.Add(val.replace(" ",""))
Next
list.Sort(New Comparison(Of Date)(Function(x As Date, y As Date) y.CompareTo(x)))
```

Comment: All this parsing stuff is unnecessary; `#10:45:00 AM#` is already a `Date` literal. So this is just a sort, and it doesn’t remove 12:00 AM as requested.

Comment: @Ryan edited to just remove the whitespace cause as i remember format should be: **#07:00:00AM#**

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in .Net for removing specific items from array, but it can be "simplified" a bit with LINQ:

```
Dim Appointment = {#10:45#, #12AM#, #12AM#}

Appointment = (From a In Appointment Where a <> #12AM# Order By a).ToArray
```

or

```
Appointment = Appointment.Except({#12AM#}).ToArray
Array.Sort(Appointment)
```

---

A bit more efficient alternative can be to use generic collection like `List` or `SortedSet` instead:

```
Dim list = New List(Of Date) From {#10:45#, #12AM#} ' or Dim list = Appointment.ToList
list.Add(#12AM#)

list.RemoveAll(Function(a) a = #12AM#)
list.Sort()
```

Comment: Why do you consider using a specialized generic collection like `List` to be "a better alternative" than LINQ?

Comment: @JimMischel I guess that was a bit subjective, so I changed it to efficient. Better as in less LINQ overhead, possibly less memory allocations, and maybe easier for someone new to programming